# Generated List consists of [Apparantly] unaccounted whitespaces in this code snippet

Tags: python, string, list, combinations

For a routine question on python programming, I was asked to generate a list of string sliced from one string (let's call it as target_string), with the length of each sliced string increasing from 1 to the length of string.

For example, if target_string is '123', I would have to generate the list like this : ['1', '2', '3', '12', '23', '123'].

For this, I wrote a code snippet that was something like this:

```
target_string = raw_input("Target String:")
length = len(target_string)
number_list = []
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        if j + i <= length:
            number_list.append(target_string[j:j + i])
print(number_list)
```

On execution of this the result was:

```
Target String:12345
['', '', '', '', '', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '12', '23', '34', '45', '123', '234', '345', '1234', '2345']
```

The first thing I noticed is that the list consists of whitespaces as elements, and the number of whitespaces is equal to the length of the target_string. Why does this happen? Any kind of clarification and help is welcome.

P.S: I have a temperory workaround to generate the list that I need:

```
target_string = raw_input("Target String:")
length = len(target_string)
number_list = []
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        if j + i <= length:
            number_list.append(target_string[j:j + i])
number_list.append(target_string)
del number_list[0:length]
target_list = [int(i) for i in number_list]
print(target_list)
```

Also feel free to suggest any changes or modifications to this, or any approach you would feel is more efficient and pythonic. Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is implemented in Pycharm, on Windows 10 , using Python 2.7, but please feel free to give the solutions in both the Python 2.7 and 3.X versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations`, then get the ones that the indexes are continuously adding 1, use `''.join(..)` for converting it o a string and add it using `.extend(..)`:

Python 2.7:

```
import itertools
target_string = raw_input("Target String:")
l=[]
for i in range(1,len(target_string)+1):
    l.extend([''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations(target_string,i) if all(int(y)-int(x)==1 for x, y in zip(i, i[1:]))])
print l
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '12', '23', '123']
```

Python 3.x:

```
import itertools
target_string = input("Target String:")
l=[]
for i in range(1,len(target_string)+1):
    l.extend([''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations(target_string,i) if all(int(y)-int(x)==1 for x, y in zip(i, i[1:]))])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '12', '23', '123']
```

Answer (score 2):

Explaining why you got whitespaces in your code snippet.
Have a look at the loop part:

```
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        if j + i <= length:
            number_list.append(target_string[j:j + i])
```

Here, both i and j gets initiated with 0.
So when we decode it, it comes like:

```
i = 0:
    j=0:
        0+0 < length
            number_list.append(for i in range(length):
            for j in range(length):
                if j + i <= length:
                    number_list.append(target_string[0:0 + 0])) --> ['']
```

and so on.....

Comment: Got it, accessing the string starting from the 0th index to the 0th index gives a whitespace, but shouldn't a string in which string[0:0] is accessed, give a 'None' as the result?? Why the whitespace?

Comment: This is how list slices work.
List[0:0] means start from index 0 and go just before index 0.
This logically means an empty string that is ''.

None has a different purpose than an empty string, It is an object that holds Null value.
Whereas, '' is a string object.